# Codeigniter PHP Warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following error message is being logged in my codeigniter application :

```
PHP Warning:  include(application/errors/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/src/dv/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 167, referer: http://localhost/dc
```

When I open the /usr/src/dv/system/core/Exceptions.php I get following on line 167 :

```
include(APPPATH.'errors/error_php.php');
```

The value of `APPPATH` is application/

If I appent the absolute path, ie `include('/usr/src/mypath'.APPPATH.'errors/error_php.php');` it is working fine.

What should I do about it ? Please suggest. I am new to code-igniter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not happy with this answer, you should not have to change php.ini for this work.

I tried to find out why the cwd (current working directory) was being reset and if this was different in newer version of php, but couldn't find anything that was useful.

However since the core still had access to APPPATH I simply changed the line in my index.php file to

```
$application_folder = getcwd().'/../application';
```

This should allow your code to be transportable still.

Comment: I agree, you shouldn't need to change php.ini to fix this problem. I had it too, and it turned out to be because I had called chdir() in my own code before the exception was thrown. So your fix was the best solution in my case.

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to mention that actually my corrected line was 
    `$application_folder = getcwd() .'/application';`

Comment: You should try and keep your application folder out of the public root.

Comment: fixed by changeing index.php at line 74 $application_folder = getcwd().'/application'... this is happening to me  because I changed my PHP version from 5.3 to a newer one , this solution works but it will generate some other errors in the mysql driver (
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 320
)... so I switched back to 5.3

Answer (score 6):

This is not a Codeigniter problem at all. You don't have your include_path set up correctly in php.ini. Basically, the include_path gives PHP a number of different directories to look in when including files.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: -@Ian Atkin, same question I asked DampeS8N if you don't mind. If either one of you answer that would be great. I'm getting the same issue as -@Piyush. Can you include the php.ini code you mention in your answer? Also, I don't recall recently changing anything in my app or php.ini which would have trigger this error. Would you have a sense of how this error happened in the first place?

Comment: @timpeterson The link in Ian's (imho better) answer gives you this code.

Comment: @DampeS8N thanks, I checked my current php.ini vs. a much older version and the following code is commented out in both files: `;include_path = ".:/php/includes"`. So if that didn't change, do you any thoughts on what might have?

Answer (score 4):

In php.ini set the folder that application is in as an include_path.

Comment: -@DampseS8N, i'm getting the same issue. Can you include the php.ini code you mention in your answer? Also, I don't recall recently changing anything in my app or php.ini which would have trigger this error. Would you have a sense of how this error happened in the first place?

Comment: @timpeterson This would be something you had to change in the ini, or in code to change the ini (Which some very messy evil frameworks and libraries might try to do) so if you have not recently installed a new library, and you have not edited the ini, this is probably not your issue.

Comment: -@DampeS8N  I didn't install a new library so I must of changed php.ini. Though as I said in my comment below I didn't change `;include_path = ".:/php/includes"`. So I'm wondering what else in php.ini or in other config files I might have unknowingly altered (httpd.conf, .htaccess?) might cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I accidentally moved the application/errors folder into a different folder (application/core) because I was too quick to click and drag the folder over. I use the NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have ran out of disk space on your root partition.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I figured out that /application/errors folder is missing
everything working fine after I copied an old errors folder

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and reason is than I am using a view which was not exist, actually spelling mistake my controller where view is called

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15883427)

Comment: ensure all view files are using is exist. in controller file.