# php codeigniter where error

Tags: php, codeigniter

good day sir/maam.. i am still a student ann new to codeigniter and still learning to generate codes.. here are my codes..

welcome.php controller

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('Crud');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['sc_data'] = $this->select2($username);
    $data2['t_data'] = $this->select($data);
    $this->load->view('quiz', $data);
}

private function select($data)
{
    $result = $this->Crud->t_select($data);
    return $result;
}

private function select2($data)
{
    $result = $this->Crud->s_course($data);
    return $result;
}
```

crud.php model

```
public function t_select($data=array())
{
    $this->db->select('fac_id');
    $this->db->where('id', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_subjects');
    return $query->result();

}

public function s_course($data = array())
{
    $this->db->select('subject_id');
    $this->db->where('stud_id', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_student_subject');
    return $query->result();
}
```

i do get errors on the where clause at t_select function.. when i do this`//$this->db->where('id', $data);` it won't have errors.. what will i do?

this are the errors..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qx1X.png)

a little help will be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the error you get

Comment: you did not pass $data to model so may be that's why you are getting error you have to do like this `$var=$this->Model_name->mode_function($data);`

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you using

Comment: this error occurs because in when you go in your view folder there is error folder inside that folder in html there is error_php.php file whhich is missing

Comment: @jovihababag then check in appllication/view/ folder is there error folder if yes. then in error folder is there is html folder and in that folder error_php.php file

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi i checked it sir but there is no an error folder..

Comment: @jovihababag yeah that's why you are getting error.error_php is used to display error's in codeigniter

Comment: are you sure you are using codeigniter 3 @jovihababag

Comment: @jovihababag then you have to do download fresh codeigniter 3 and copy error folder in view folder of project may this help

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. i can now detect the problem.. I erased the error folder recently so that's why i can't detect it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CI-3 error message templates are in  application/views/errors/html.
deleting the error folder provides such messages.

For more see this [Codeigniter PHP Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689016/codeigniter-php-warning)