# Why Warning in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, warnings

Why warning this :

```
Warning: include(/home/rifdaym/Workspace/alpha/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/alpha/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269


Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/rifdaym/Workspace/alpha/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /home/rifdaym/Workspace/alpha/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
```

I think, nothing wrong in file exception :

```
ob_start();
include($templates_path.$template.'.php');
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $buffer;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689016/codeigniter-php-warning

Comment: my file in server @RanjeetSingh i can't chnge file php.ini